# What's the meaning of angle from rotation martrix?

Tags: c++, opencv, euler-angles

Now I'm working for calculating the head pose. I use solvePnPRansac() in opencv and get the rotation and translation vector.Then, I use Rodrigues() to get my rotation matrix and get three angles from the rotation matrix. But from my data,the angle rotated by x axis is 172 degrees. I'm very confusing about this data.That means my head rotate 172 degrees by x axis?Could anyone help me with this problem? Thank you in advance!

Comment: please create a full example including images and matrix data, camera calibration etc.

Comment: I'm very sorry that I didn't reply to you recently.I'm a little busy these days.I did with my project in this method.http://www.morethantechnical.com/2010/03/19/quick-and-easy-head-pose-estimation-with-opencv-w-code/

Comment: But I found that the video result shows that the rotation of the x axis in 172 degrees.I'm very confused with this result.Thank you for your response!